Ruby on Rails: File field with stimulus controller breaks when uploading a second file
I have this file field:
    <div data-controller="file-upload">
                <%= file_field_tag "revision_photos[photo][]",
                                   name: "revision_photos[photo][]",
                                   class: "w-full",
                                   id: "photo_#{index}",
                                   disabled: !is_checked,
                                   data: {
                                     rules_form_target: "photo",
                                     file_upload_target: "file",
                                     action: "file-upload#fileChanged change->file-upload#fileChanged change->resize-image#resizeImage",
                                     controller: "resize-image"
                                   },
                                   accept: "image/*",
                                   capture: "environment" %>

                <label for="photo_#{index}" class="cursor-pointer">
                  <span data-file-upload-target="filename" class="text-gray-500">No hay archivo seleccionado</span>
                </label>
              </div>

it has two stimulus controllers, the one giving me problems is the controller to resize a image in client side:
// app/javascript/controllers/resize_image_controller.js
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"
export default class ResizeImageController extends Controller {
    static targets = ["file"];

    resizeImage(event) {
        const input = event.target;
        if (!input.files.length) return;
        const file = input.files[0];

        if (!file.type.startsWith('image/')) return;

        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (e) => {
            const img = new Image();
            img.onload = () => {
                const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

                const maxWidth = 400;
                const scaleFactor = maxWidth / img.width;

                canvas.width = maxWidth;
                canvas.height = img.height * scaleFactor;

                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

                canvas.toBlob((blob) => {
                    const newFile = new File([blob], file.name, {
                        type: file.type,
                        lastModified: Date.now()
                    });

                    const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();
                    dataTransfer.items.add(newFile);
                    input.files = dataTransfer.files;

                    // Trigger any existing change handlers after updating the file input
                    input.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { bubbles: true }));
                }, file.type);
            };
            img.src = e.target.result;
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
}

When I still didn't have that controller it worked fine, if I uploaded a second file the first one was overwritten, so the field showed the name of the second file and it was the one uploaded.
But after adding the controller, now when I add a second file, the field starts to show both files intermittently, and the file that uploaded is just by luck.
¿How can I fix it so it works as before? I can't remove the controller and doing the resize in backend, since I need to keep the data submited as light as possible.
I tried using the line          input.value = "";before the new DataTransfer, but it didn't work

you need to show the rest of the code, so the issue is reproducible.
